# Making processing intensive web code (chess engine)

Tags: javascript, c++, chess

I've made some a couple of chess engines in **Processing** (a simplified Java language) and wanted to make one on a website. I'm guessing JavaScript would be the most obvious thing to make it in, but I wanted to know if there are other options before I get into it. I've never made something that processing intensive for web.

I've looked around and it seems like C++ can somehow be made to work with web code but I've never done that and don't know much about it. Is it possible to do the low intensive things like drawing in JavaScript and the move generation in C++? Is there a better option?

**Edit**: I put **Processing** (the language) in bold to differentiate it

Comment: I **do not** recommend writing a chess engine in purely javascript, it will under-perform, be incredibly hard to debug, and ultimately freeze the users web-browser if allowed to search deep in a chess move tree.

Comment: So send the heavy processing somewhere else basically right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a cross browser client-side solution, then there is no single cross-browser way to use C++ in your viewer's browser.  Cross browser solutions consist of javascript (recommended), java (being phased out on desktops and generally not available on mobile) and Adobe Flash (not available on mobile).

If you want it all client-side, what I would suggest is that you write in client-side javascript and do as much processing as you can in webworkers which are separate threads of execution.  Those separate threads can do as much calculation as you want, but need to use messaging to communicate back to the main javascript thread in order to actually modify the DOM or interact with the user.

---

Or, as a browser web-app, you could keep the chess logic on the server in C++ or whatever server-side language you want to use and use client-side Ajax calls to ask the server to calculate the next move.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon how you want to architect this.

If you want to make it run without server-side support, you will pretty much limited to JavaScript.  (Sure, you could actually host your existing Java code and libraries, available as a Java applet - or something in Flash or another plugin for that matter - but especially given HTML 5, etc., the focus is on JavaScript.)

Otherwise, you can implement the UI and other elements with JavaScript, and use AJAX to have it communicate / offload the heavy processing to a back-end server.  (At this point, you would essentially need to host a chess engine for use from your website.)

Comment: I will look into Ajax, thank you. It sounds like (from jfriend00's post) that Java and Flash may not be the best option.

Comment: @asimes - agreed, I'd either do it in JavaScript, or offload it to a back-end server using AJAX.  Given everything that JavaScript is used for today, implementing the engine within JavaScript is not far-fetched what-so-ever.

Answer (score 1):

Write the chess engine with any language you so desire. Create an interface for communicating with your chess engine or even better use an existing standard chess engine interface. Use either of the following two "standard" interfaces

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_Engine_Communication_Protocol
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Chess_Interface

Once you have thoroughly debugged your chess engine and are happy with it, you can approach the problem of writing a web UI for it as a completely independent problem. You can accomplish communication between a chess engine server and a web-server/website by an intermediate layer of your choice. One such option is:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Furthermore, if you use a standard chess interface you can swap out your own chess engine for any third party chess engine satisfying the interface that you chose.

Comment: I wanted to write the engine myself, those are engines not engine checkers right? I haven't used Ajax, I'll look into it

Comment: @asimes The first two links I provided are interfaces as defined in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing) They are not themselves the chess engine, they just simply state what functionality your chess engine must implement to have it play.

Comment: Oh, then I think I understand that, this would be the third one I make